# Implementing AirPrint with DNS-SD

Tags: ios, dns, bonjour, airprint

## Background

I'm trying to implement AirPrint through static DNS, like documented on http://dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html. The iPad gets the dns search domain "lan" through DHCP, and I verified that in Settings-WLAN. I think I created all necessary entries in the right places, the iPad however doesn't find my printer or if it happened to find it, it showed a lock after the printers name and didn't print. (iOS version is 6.0.1)

Has anyone here a clue, as to why iOS does not find the printer or if it finds it, why it shows it as locked?

This is my setup (simplified with example domain)

### DNS entries

#### Redirect to browse domain

```
PTR b._dns-sd._udp.lan = bonjour.lan
PTR lb._dns-sd._udp.lan = bonjour.lan
```

#### Printer entries

```
PTR _ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan = TestPrinter._ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan
PTR _universal._sub._ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan = TestPrinter._ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan
SRV TestPrinter._ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan = 0 0 631 mfp.printer
TXT TestPrinter._ipp._tcp.bonjour.lan  

txtvers=1  
qtotal=1  
rp=Print  
ty=Toshiba MFP  
adminurl=http://mfp.printer  
note=Shared MFP  
priority=0  
product=(Toshiba eStudio 351c)  
printer-state=3  
printer-type=0xC0B0DE  
Transparent=T  
Binary=T  
Fax=F  
Color=T  
Duplex=T  
Staple=F  
Copies=T  
Collate=T  
Punch=F  
Bind=F  
Sort=T  
Scan=T  
pdl=application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/postscript,image/jpeg,image/png,image/urf  
URF=none
```

Comment: This is strange, the code-fencing (4 leading spaces) isn't working...

Comment: @JasonSalaz It's because there was a list preceding it. You have to either double indent to make the code part of the list, or get rid of the list. `<code>` tags would also work.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Caveats: I don't own an AirPrint device nor do I have one available elsewhere for testing. So I'm not talking from my own experience in the following answer...</sub>

---

1. **First,** when publishing a printer (AirPrint or not) from a DNS server (*"static, Wide Area Bonjour"*), you should include ALL of the TXT record key/value pairs which are listed in the [current Bonjour Printing specification](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/printing-specification/bonjourprinting-1.2.pdf).

   A tabular overview is listed in chapter 9 of the specification document (for all details please read the complete chapter):

   [image: Printer Description TXT Record Keys for Bonjour/AirPrint]
2. **Second,** the Bonjour Printing *specification requires that for a printer you always have to register the LPD protocol (`_printer._tcp`), even if the device does not support it (`port = 0`) !*.

   The reason for this seemingly braindead requirement is this: LPD is considered the "flagship" protocol for service discovery related to printing. (Meaning: if you own the service instance name for `_printer` then you also own it for `_pdl-datastream`, `_ipp`, `_ipps`, etc.)

   Some older versions of OS X enforced this. They would not work without it. Newer versions (and probably the next *macOS* version too) are less dogmatic and more pragmatic...

   In your case the `air` (has nothing to do with AirPrint, but means s.th. like *authentication information required*), `TLS`, `UUID`, `usb_MFG`, `usb_CMD` and `usb_MDL` keys are missing (even if you'd use `""` as their key values).
3. **Third,** please take to heart the general rule about the trailing dot for domain names. Details are outlined here:

   - [dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html](http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html)
4. **Fourth,** maybe you also should enclose your key values in quotes. Example:

   ```
   pdl="application/pdf,image/urf"
   ```

   not

   ```
   pdl=application/pdf,image/urf
   ```
5. **Fifth,** in general, what is quoted above in the OP code block does not look like a valid format for a [*zone file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) to me. (I notice that the original question has been edited by other people than the OP, so I won't comment on the details...)

Answer (score 1):

Answering 10 years later because this was still one of the first search results I found, and it wasn't quite enough to get me to a working config.

First, the [ServerStaticSetup](http://dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html) page you previously linked now (if it didn't before) has a section at the bottom with a subtitle "How to set up Wide-Area AirPrint" which covers the basics pretty well.

Second, the link in @Kurt Pfeifle's response to the AirPrint / Bonjour Printing standard on apple.com have broken, but this one works as of now: https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/printing-specification/bonjourprinting-1.2.1.pdf

It seems you need at minimum the following:

- the "browse" PTR record for your domain
- your DNS client configured to search in that domain

  - -OR- a reverse-lookup record for lb._dns-sd._udp, in the "domain" of your in-addr.arpa entry

    - e.g. if your device's IP is 1.2.3.4, you need a record like `lb._dns-sd._udp.4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. PTR yourdomain.tld`
- an LPR / `_printer` PTR record and corresponding SRV record

  - the SRV record can (and likely should) point to port 0
- a PDL / `_pdl-datastream` PTR and corresponding SRV record
- a PDL TXT record
- an IPP / `_ipp` PTR and corresponding SRV record
- an IPP TXT record
- an IPP.URF / `_universal._sub._ipp` PTR record (pointing at the IPP SRV/TXT domain name)

I reaped the contents needed for the TXT records from mDNS broadcasts coming from the printer, using a machine on the same local wifi network.

- On Linux (with avahi installed) you can use `sudo killall -USR1 avahi-daemon` to dump all records it knows about in zone file format to syslog.

  - It's kind of annoying to extract that from syslog, so I used `avahi-browse -d local -a -r -t` to get the same data formatted slightly differently.
- On Mac and Windows (with Bonjour installed) you can use the `dns-sd -Z <name>` command to dump individual records in zone file format.

I'm using DNSMasq, with an HP 8020 series MFP, and this configuration is currently working from the DNS server side:

```
ptr-record=b._dns-sd._udp.domain.tld,domain.tld
ptr-record=lb._dns-sd._udp.domain.tld,domain.tld

address=/basement-printer.domain.tld/,1.2.3.4

# LPR *must* be advertised, but setting port to 0 shows it's not supported
ptr-record=_printer._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer._printer._tcp.domain.tld
srv-host=basement-printer._printer._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer.domain.tld,0

# IPP on port 631
ptr-record=_ipp._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer._ipp._tcp.domain.tld
# must also advertise URF / _universal for AirPrint to auto-find us
ptr-record=_universal._sub._ipp._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer._ipp._tcp.domain.tld
srv-host=basement-printer._ipp._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer.domain.tld,631
txt-record=basement-printer._ipp._tcp.domain.tld,"Fax=T","rfo=ipp/faxout","mopria-certified=2.0","Scan=T","kind=document,envelope,photo,postcard","URF=CP1,MT1-2-8-9-10-11,PQ3-4-5,RS300-600,SRGB24,OB9,OFU0,W8-16,DEVW8-16,DEVRGB24-48,ADOBERGB24-48,DM3,IS1,V1.4,FN3","PaperMax=legal-A4","pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,image/jpeg,image/urf,image/pwg-raster,application/PCLm","Duplex=T","Color=T","usb_MDL=OfficeJet Pro 8020 series","usb_MFG=HP","ty=HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series","product=(HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series)","UUID=bd06fe8e-e45f-5e04-3ca1-150938ffc67b","rp=ipp/print","TLS=1.2","qtotal=1","priority=30","note=","adminurl=http://HP3024A9686036-783.local./#hId-pgAirPrint","txtvers=1"

# PDL on port 9100
ptr-record=_pdl-datastream._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer._pdl-datastream._tcp.domain.tld
srv-host=basement-printer._pdl-datastream._tcp.domain.tld,basement-printer.domain.tld,9100
txt-record=basement-printer._pdl-datastream._tcp.domain.tld,"pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,image/jpeg,image/urf,image/pwg-raster,application/PCLm","usb_MDL=OfficeJet Pro 8020 series","usb_MFG=HP","mac=DE:AD:BE:EF:DE:AD","UUID=bd06fe8e-e45f-5e04-3ca1-150938ffc67b","priority=40","rp=","txtvers=1"
```

Finally, because I think others may be doing the same thing-- to configure the DNS search domain for a WireGuard iOS client, you must add it to the "DNS Server" field after a comma... e.g. `1.2.3.4,domain.tld` .